# HTML / javascript dynamically creating different postmessage replies depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm not quite sure how I should name this better.

Anyway, I'm dealing with a postmessage interface that receives and sends data between its iframe child. It basically sends very simple messages: either score related to the game in the iframe or save/load requests.

What I'm trying to do is make it possible for the user to have more than one save "file" at once, using the concat method. I'm basically making separate save states into one large string by combining them with a separator and separating them when I need to access them for load requests.

Here's how I handle save requests from the game at the moment:

```
            var states = JSON.stringify(data.gameState);
            var newstate = {state: gameState};
            var savesArray = savestring.split("||");
            savesArray.unshift(newstate);
            if (savesArray.length > 5){
                savesArray.pop();
            }
            var state = savesArray.join("||");
```

and then I send the 'state' back to the database. 
The problem that I'm having is how I would be able to let the user decide which of the 0-5 save files he wants to choose to open (=> send back as a load request).

What I'm doing at the moment as a way to avoid the problem altogether is send the first state using

```
var first_state = loaded_state.split("||")[0];
```

but I was wondering if there's any neat way to give the user a button box/div when the load request is received in the parent HTML with buttons deciding which index save state is sent back to the iframe. The biggest problem I have with this is how I can properly build the button to communicate & send the load request dynamically.

I already have a function that I use for other things in the page to dynamically create a button, but I'm not 100% sure if I can work with it to suit my needs here or if it's even the best approach in the first place.

```
        function play(name, URL) {
        var element = document.createElement("button");

        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("value", URL);
        element.setAttribute("id", "gamebutton");
        element.innerHTML = name;
        element.setAttribute("style", "display:block");
        element.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success btn-block");
        element.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("iframeID").src = this.getAttribute("value");
            document.getElementById("iframeID").width = "95%";
            document.getElementById("iframeID").height = "750 px";
            document.getElementById("iframeID").style.display = "block";

            document.getElementById("hiddenScore").style.display = "block";
            var gameelement = document.getElementById("gamediv");
            gameelement.style.display = "block";

            var miscarea = document.getElementById("misc_div");
            miscarea.style.display = "none";
        };
```

I was thinking of making it into a modal box, but the uncertainty of whether or not I would be able to smoothly create the buttons I need for it has made me hesitate whether or not I want to go the extra mile to make multiple saves possible.

Edit:

This is how the message is sent back to the iframe. As you can see, being able to create buttons for each of the indexes (var first_state = loaded_state.split("||")[0];) would mean that the code would otherwise be the same for all buttons

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'get_detail_game_instance' game.pk %}",
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                $.ajaxSettings.beforeSend(xhr, settings);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var loaded_state = JSON.parse(data.state);
                var first_state = loaded_state.split("||")[0];
                console.log(loaded_state);
                var message = {
                    "messageType" : "LOAD",
                    "gameState" : first_state
                };

                event.source.postMessage(message, eventSave.origin);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            }
        });
```

The event is received through a simple eventlistener and the event data contains whether or not it's a score, load or save request

Comment: If you have a finite number of messages, put them in an array an then use array methods such as `forEach()` and `.map()`. Not sure how you are using postMessage so I'm not certain as to what would be appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I'll edit the question a bit more, in that case